# Proof a set is a subset of another set involving union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove the following: $$(A∪C)-B⊆(A-B)∪C$$
I started out by assuming you have a generic element $x∈(A∪C)-B$.  Then we know that $x∈(A∪C)$ and $x∉B$.  Since $x∈(A∪C)$, $x∈A$ or $x∈C$.  Thus, all elements in $(A∪C)-B$ are not elements of B.  Further, they are either members of A or C.  Thus, all such elements $x∈(A∪C)-B$ would be a valid subset of $(A-B)∪C$ does not include elements from B.  It does include elements from A or C.  Thus, $(A∪C)-B⊆(A-B)∪C$.

I kind of have the general reasoning down, but I am not sure what I have constitutes a valid proof.  Is this proof valid or could it be improved or amended in some way?

Comment: $(A\cup C)\setminus B = (A\cup C)\cap B^c = (A\cap B^c)\cup (C\cap B^c) \subseteq (A\cap B^c)\cup C = (A\setminus B)\cup C$.  You can do element chasing if you prefer... but I think the algebraic approach is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking from your proof at $x \in (A \cup C)$, and $x \notin B$. If $x \in C \implies x \in (A-B)\cup C$, and if $x \in A \implies x \in (A-B) \implies x \in (A-B)\cup C$. Thus $x \in (A-B)\cup C$